# Which is better for designing API between send all needed data together or separately?

Tags: api

I'm trying to design API for mobile application (think about Facebook feed, we are trying to create API for this type of view) but I'm wonder what's pro and cons for each type of API and what type do you prefer?

**Type 1: All we need is single API call**

Url: `/product/list`

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Product1",
    "summary": "Lorem ipsum",
    "feature_image": "http://www.example.com/picture.jpg",
    "owner": {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "John Dev",
        "profile_image": "http://wwww.example.com/john.jpg",
        "user_level": "Expert"
    }
}, ... and 20 items here ...]
```

---

**Type 2: Get product list first and pull data of owner later**

Url: `/product/list`

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Product1",
    "summary": "Lorem ipsum",
    "feature_image": "http://www.example.com/picture.jpg",
    "owner_id": "10"
}, ... and 20 items here ...]
```

Url: `/user/public_data?user_id=10`

```
{
    "id": "10",
    "name": "John Dev",
    "profile_image": "http://wwww.example.com/john.jpg",
    "user_level": "Expert"
}
```

---

**Type 3: Get list of product id and owner, then pull both separately**

Url: `/product/list`

```
[{
    "product_id": "1",
    "owner_id": "10"
}, ... and 20 items here ...]
```

Url: `/product/detail?product_id=1`

```
{
    "name": "Product1",
    "summary": "Lorem ipsum",
    "feature_image": "http://www.example.com/picture.jpg",
}
```

Url: `/user/public_data?user_id=10`

```
{
    "id": "10",
    "name": "John Dev",
    "profile_image": "http://wwww.example.com/john.jpg",
    "user_level": "Expert"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go with Type 1. Making multiple api calls can get expensive. If you can provide all of the data in one shot that is preferable unless the data set you'll be getting back is so large that you want to paginate it server side. 20 objects to sort through takes very little time.